# sent email verification link with php condeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to send an email verification link to the user with PHP CodeIgniter.

This is my controller function.

```
public function Sent_Confirmation_Email()
{
    $emailid  = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $verificationLink = base_url() . 'MainController/Confirm_Activation/'.$emailid;

    $msg .= "Please use the link below to activate your account..<br /><br /><br />";

    $msg .= "<a href='".$verificationLink."' target='_blank'>VERIFY EMAIL</a><br /><br /><br />";

    $msg .= "Kind regards,<br />";

    $msg .= "Company Name";         

    if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    }        

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'sender@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password'
    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->isHTML(true);
    $this->email->from("sender@gmail.com");
    $this->email->to("$emailid");
    $this->email->subject("Email Confirmation - Courses and Tutors");
    $this->email->message($msg);

    if($this->email->send())
    {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'A confirmation email has been sent to ' . $emailid .'. Please activate your account using the link provided.');
        redirect(base_url() . 'MainController/EConfirmationPage/'.$emailid);
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

Note that I am sending emails from my localhost. I receive the email but the problem is it shows the html tags as well. This is the email which I received:

```
Please use the link below to activate your account..<br /><br /><br /><a
href='http://localhost/tutorhunt/MainController/Confirm_Activation/fareedshuja@gmail.com'
target='_blank'>VERIFY EMAIL</a><br /><br /><br />Kind regards,<br />Company
Name
```

Comment: Use `$msg .= "<a href='".$verificationLink."' target='_blank'>VERIFY EMAIL</a><br /><br /><br />";`

Comment: Do you have any error ? Do you know if the email is sent or not ? Did you check in junk mail ?

Comment: Maybe... it is not properly use 'redirect' function.

Comment: $verificationLink = base_url() . 'MainController/Confirm_Activation/'.$emailid;

Comment: I don't have any error. The record is inserted in database but I cannot receive the email. is there anything wrong with the redirect(base_url()) which I used??

Comment: in `href=''` you have to give only `url` not a `redirect(...)`

Comment: Now I receive the email but the problem is it shows the html tags as well. This is the email which I received: Please use the link below to activate your account..<br /><br /><br /><a
href='http://localhost/tutorhunt/MainController/Confirm_Activation/fareedshuja@gmail.com'
target='_blank'>VERIFY EMAIL</a><br /><br /><br />Kind regards,<br />Company
Name

Comment: Use `$this->email->set_mailtype("html");`

Comment: Codeignitor's default mail library sucks to be frank. It has several issues including TLS connections. PHPMailer is much better than the default one. Why not use that instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize email library and add mailtype as following

```
    $this->email->initialize(array(
          'protocol'  => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mailserver',
          'smtp_user' => 'user',
          'smtp_pass' => 'password',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'crlf'      => "\r\n",
          'newline'   => "\r\n",
          'mailtype'  => 'html',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

To Send Verification Link In Email Using Email Template is simpler than adding HTML content as a message and send it.

- Creare an array of the variable which you want to send in an email.
- Load that email template view and load that variable array and set the variable in the template properly.

Here is the code sample:

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->isHTML(true);
$this->email->from("sender@gmail.com");
$this->email->to("$emailid");
$this->email->subject("Email Confirmation - Courses and Tutors");   

$template_data = array(
        'verificationLink' => base_url() . 'MainController/Confirm_Activation/'.$emailid,
        'message' => 'Please use the link below to activate your account..',
        'company_name' => 'test company'                            
);

$body = $this->load->view ('your_view.php', ['template_data'=>$template_data], TRUE); //Set the variable in template Properly
$this->email->message ( $body );

if($this->email->send())  
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'A confirmation email has been sent to ' . $emailid .'. Please activate your account using the link provided.');
    redirect(base_url() . 'MainController/EConfirmationPage/'.$emailid);
} else {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```